# Angular Async Validator Is Not Working Properly

Tags: angular, angular-validation

In my component, I am trying to change the password and in my form, I ask the user for an old password if that password matches with the password in DB he/she is allowed to change the password. I am trying to validate the password using async validator which tells whether the old password is true or not but in my case async validator is always false whether the entered password is right or wrong. Below Given Is My Async Validator Function

```
   passwordCheck(control : AbstractControl)
  {
return this.usrservice.check_password(control.value,this.logged_in_usr_details['password']).map(res=>{
return res['matched']?null:{invalidPassword:true}
 })
   }
```

Below is My service file Code

```
   check_password(pass,oldpass)
  {
   const params= new HttpParams().set('pass',pass).set('old_pass',oldpass);
   return this.http.get(environment.api_url+'/users/compare_pass',{params:params});
  }
```

Below Is My backend Nodejs Code

```
router.get('/compare_pass/',(req,res)=>{
const queryParams = req.query;
const pass=queryParams.pass;
const old_pass=queryParams.old_pass;
bcrypt.compare(pass,old_pass, function(err, response) {
if(response===true)
  {
    res.send({matched:true});
  }
else {

res.send({notmatched:true});
  }
})

})
```

Comment: return null?res['matched']:{invalidPassword:true} looks weird

Comment: kindly look at it now